# Install z3 library for Ocaml by Cygwin64 (Windows 11)

Tags: cygwin, ocaml, z3, opam

I am trying to install z3 library for Ocaml in Cygwin64 Terminal (Windows 11). I get the following error that it can't find -lstdc++ even though the liabrary is already installed.

```
# cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-fvisibility-inlines-hidden’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
# ocamlmklib -o api/ml/z3ml  -I api/ml -L. api/ml/z3native_stubs.o api/ml/z3enums.cmo api/ml/z3native.cmo api/ml/z3.cmo  -lz3 -lstdc++ -cclib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11 -ccopt -L$(ocamlfind printconf destdir)/stublibs -dllpath $(ocamlfind printconf destdir)/stublibs
# ** Fatal error: Cannot find file "-lstdc++"
# make: *** [Makefile:5081: api/ml/z3ml.cma] Error 2
# make: Leaving directory '/home/doanha/.opam/4.14.0+flambda+mingw64_for_utop/.opam-switch/build/z3.4.11.2/build'

<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build z3 4.11.2
└─
╶─ No changes have been performed
```

Does anyone know what is the problem or how can I fix it?

I even set up the LDFLAGS points to it:

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11"
```

or copy -lstdc++  to /usr/lib/

Comment: How did you start your build? You should start with `python scripts/mk_make.py -ml`; and if it can't find c++ libraries the next step should fail when you do `cd build; make`. Don't forget the `-ml` argument in call to `mk_make.py`.

Comment: Not a solution, but a suggestion: WSL2 is often a saner way to work with OCaml on Windows than Cygwin.

Comment: I use opam "opam install z3", but also when I build it from the sourse "python scripts/mk_make.py --ml;  cd build; make; make install" I got the same error that it can not find -lstdc++

Comment: Can you compile c++ programs? See if you can compile a simple c++ program and run it successfully first.

Comment: Yes I can run c or c++ programs. Also I cand find the liabrary "$ find / -name libstdc++.*
/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/libstdc++.a

Comment: the import shared lib is `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/libstdc++.dll.a` the shared lib is `/usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll` and belongs to `libstdc++6` package

Comment: You can modify the build script and remove libstdc++ as a workaround (I added it a couple of years ago). It will break z3 in the OCaml toplevel (i.e., you wouldn't be able to load z3 in the interactive interpreter) but it should still work (though I can't really be sure with cygwin) in the native mode. 
See also https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/pull/4468/files#diff-a1c713be31db2093bcea8fdd2a396e49430d091f043142a1093bd2a5aa173610R1960

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, but unfortunately, I have tried multiple different approaches, and none of them have been successful. I even attempted to remove libstdc++ as a workaround, but encountered another error that read, '** Fatal error: Error while reading libz3.dll.a: Out of memory. make: *** [Makefile:5239: api/ml/z3ml.cma] Error 2'." And still not find out what causes the problem yet.

Comment: A similar issue was raised at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6708. Their situation is different though: Trying to install on a Mac, not Windows. But perhaps their solution can work for you too?

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the `libstdc` package when installing Cygwin?
[image]

If not, it may be useful to reinstall [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) with all dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I indeed did, and the library was there, but it continued to raise complaints. I couldn't find out the errors. Consequently, I decided to give up on Windows and install it on Linux